# Using multiple Parameters after WHERE in SELECT query

Tags: c#, parameters, oledbcommand

I'm trying to avoid populating a table and using multiple queries and statements to select a specific ID representing a Holiday from a DataGridView.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

The code I've got so far is as follows :

```
string HolidayIDQuery = "SELECT ID FROM [Holiday] WHERE PayrollNo=@PayrollNo + StartDate=@StartDate + EndDate=@EndDate"; 
OleDbCommand GetHolID = new OleDbCommand(HolidayIDQuery, conn);
GetHolID.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PayrollNo", GotPayroll);
GetHolID.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", OleDbType.Date).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.Rows[LineIndex].Cells[1].Value);
GetHolID.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate", OleDbType.Date).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.Rows[LineIndex].Cells[2].Value);
int HolID = Convert.ToInt32(GetHolID.ExecuteScalar());
```

I get this Error on the bottom line.

> Exception thrown: 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

Comment: Use `and` instead of `+`!

Comment: `+` is not the same as `AND`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `AND` in your `WHERE` clause:

`WHERE PayrollNo=@PayrollNo AND StartDate=@StartDate AND EndDate=@EndDate;`

You might also want to try an SQL tutorial: https://www.google.com/webhp?q=sql%20tutorial

Comment: i'm not sure why this was downvoted - can the downvoter explain?

Comment: Cheers everyone! Can't believe I didn't try this! Thanks!
EDIT: I'll be marking this as an answer as soon as I am able

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be an error in your query. Instead of

```
SELECT ID 
FROM [Holiday] 
WHERE PayrollNo=@PayrollNo + StartDate=@StartDate + EndDate=@EndDate
```

try this:

```
SELECT ID FROM [Holiday] 
WHERE PayrollNo=@PayrollNo 
      AND StartDate=@StartDate 
      AND EndDate=@EndDate"
```

Comment: Thank you, I've done this and it works great! Can't believe I hadn't tried this yet!